# Knockout.js Runtime Error

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to loop through out the list of items in a collection and compare each item if email address of item to be added on the collection already exist but I got run time error "JavaScript runtime error: Function expected". Please anyone help me what is missing with my code below?

**ViewModel**

```
self.AddReceiver = function () {
        var newReceiverData = ko.toJS(self.newReceiver);
        if (ReceiverValidate()) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.receivers(), function (item) {
                if (item.EmailAddress() == newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress) {
                    alert("Email already exist on the list");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            self.receivers.push({
                EmailAddress: newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress,
                FirstName: newReceiverData.receiverfirstname,
                LastName: newReceiverData.receiverlastname
            });
            ClearReceiverInput();
        }
    };
```

**Screenshot error**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `item.EmailAddress()` is an observable? Try it with `if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.EmailAddress) == newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress)`

Comment: And as a sidenote `ko.utils.arrayForEach` does not stop if you `return false;` it will iterate through all the elements in the array no matter what. So should consider to use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` isntead...

Comment: @nemesv yes it's not observable but it's a property of self.receivers = ko.observableArray();

Comment: If EmailAddress is not observable you cannot call it with `item.EmailAddress()` because it is not a function. So you need to write `item.EmailAddress` or use `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` as I mentioned above. It does not matter that it is inside an `observableArray` because the `observableArray` does not magically turn its item observable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems EmailAddress is not an observable.